# How can I know in JavaScript which <li> tag is clicked on a page?

Tags: javascript, css, html, web-deployment

I am new in web development.

I want to add `.active` in `<li>` when it is clicked and remove it from the previous `<li>`. I also want to know how to determine which `<li>` has been clicked.

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I have more than one on the page menu. I want a function such that when a user clicks that `<li>`, the function returns that `<li>` object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using jQuery ?

Comment: Did you even search for this answer?

Comment: I am not using jQuery http://stackoverflow.com/users/1517335/bviale

Comment: yes I search before Asking http://stackoverflow.com/users/1676224/aaron
But all answer are in jQuery but I need without jQuery

Answer (score 2):

here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rn3nc/1/

```
   var selector, elems, makeActive;

    selector = '.nav li';

    elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

    makeActive = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
            elems[i].classList.remove('active');

        this.classList.add('active');
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
        elems[i].addEventListener('mousedown', makeActive);
```

Not my code, I just google searched and found this on jsfiddle. FYI

Comment: thanks http://stackoverflow.com/users/1676224/aaron

Comment: no problem @MKRNaqeebi (if you could mark my answer as correct by clicking the tick/check mark next to my answer please)